# Javascript subscribe button only works when I click the icon not the rest of the button

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick, subscribe

I have a subscribe to user profile button that only works when I click the rss font awesome icon, not the rest of the button. I have tried a couple of rewrites where I make the button element the clicked event but they don't work at all.

Here is the code that works only when clicking the icon element:

```php
            <button class='subscribe-button profile-subscribe'> 
                <?php if ($profile->userSubscribed): ?>
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user-check subscribe" data-user='<?= esc($profile->username);?>'></i>Subscribed
                <?php else: ?>   
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-rss subscribe" data-user='<?= esc($profile->username);?>'>
                    </i> Subscribe
                <?php endif ?>
            </button>
```

```php
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var csrfName = "<?= csrf_token(); ?>";
        var csrfHash = "<?= csrf_hash(); ?>"; 

    // If user clicks the subscribe button
        $(".subscribe").on("click", function () {
            var userProfile = $(this).data("user");
            $clicked_btn = $(this);

            if ($clicked_btn.hasClass("fa-solid fa-rss")) {
                action = "subscribe";
            } else if ($clicked_btn.hasClass("fa-solid fa-user-check")) {
                action = "unsubscribe";
            }

            $.ajax ({
                url: "<?= base_url(); ?>/users/members/view_profile/<?= $profile->username;?>",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    [csrfName]: csrfHash,
                    "action": action,
                    "user_profile": userProfile,
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var res = data;
                    csrfName = res.csrfName;
                    csrfHash = res.csrfHash;

                    if (action == "subscribe") {
                        $clicked_btn.removeClass("fa-solid fa-rss");
                        $clicked_btn.addClass("fa-solid fa-user-check");
                    } else if (action == "unsubscribe") {
                        $clicked_btn.removeClass("fa-solid fa-user-check");
                        $clicked_btn.addClass("fa-solid fa-rss");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is one attempt at making the whole button clickable:

```php
<button class='subscribe-button profile-subscribe subscribe' id='<?= esc($profile->username); ?>'>   
    <i class="fa-solid fa-rss"></i> Subscribe
</button>
```

```php
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        var csrfName = "<?= csrf_token(); ?>";
        var csrfHash = "<?= csrf_hash(); ?>"; 

    // If user clicks the subscribe button
        $(".subscribe").on("click", function (event) {
            var userProfile = this.id;
            $clicked_btn = $(this);

            if ($clicked_btn.hasClass("fa-solid fa-rss")) {
                action = "subscribe";
            } else if ($clicked_btn.hasClass("fa-solid fa-user-check")) {
                action = "unsubscribe";
            }

            $.ajax ({
                url: "<?= base_url(); ?>/users/members/view_profile/<?= $profile->username;?>",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    [csrfName]: csrfHash,
                    "action": action,
                    "user_profile": userProfile,
                },
                headers: {
                    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var res = data;
                    csrfName = res.csrfName;
                    csrfHash = res.csrfHash;
                
                    if ($('.subscribe').hasClass('subscribed')) {
                        $('.subscribe').removeClass('subscribed');
                        $('.subscribe').html('<i class="fa-solid fa-rss"</i>Subscribe');
                        
                    } else {
                        $('.like').addClass('subscribed');
                        $('.like').html('<i class="fa-solid fa-user-check">Subscribed');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: because the data attribute/click is on the icon and not the button. Click the button you are not clicking on the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea with changing your click handler to select your button instead of the icon, but you missed the step after that, which is changing how you detect whether it's a "subscribe" or "unsubscribe" that was clicked. When the click handler was on the icon, the class was on the clicked element directly, but when you changed to the parent button, you have to select down into the button's children to look at the class on the icon to determine if it's "subscribe" or "unsubscribe". It should be an easy fix:

```
$clicked_btn = $(this);
let $icon = $clicked_btn.find('i').first();

if ($icon.hasClass("fa-solid fa-rss")) {
    action = "subscribe";
} else if ($icon.hasClass("fa-solid fa-user-check")) {
    action = "unsubscribe";
}
```